# How to not calculate the weekend in penalty using php

Tags: php

I want to prevent calculation in fines when the day is Saturday and Sunday or Only Sunday not include in fines. I think it's better if we use the borrowdate,currentdate, and returndate to fully functions from my database Thank you!

```
$borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_return']);
$returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date']); 
$currentdate = new Datetime();        
$fines = 0;
if($currentdate > $returndate){
     $days = $borrowdate->diff($returndate ?? $currentdate, true)->days;
     echo "₱ ". $fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 15 : 0;
     $fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
     mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
}
```

Comment: Use w for day of week. 0 for Sunday and 6 for Sartuday

Comment: @peter can you give me an example of your codes?

Comment: You can call the format function on the `DateTime` object passing in the **w** flag and dertemine the day of week based onn that result. Exactly what @vladatr 's answer does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should count the number of working days, and than calculate your fine.

```
$returnDate= new DateTime( '2017-08-17' );
    $today= new DateTime( '2017-08-21 00:23:44' );

    $returnDate->setTime(0,0);
    $today->setTime(0,0);

    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
    $period = new DatePeriod($returnDate, $interval, $today);

$weekendDays = 0;
$totalDays = 0;
foreach ( $period as $p ) {
    $totalDays++;
  if($p->format( "w" )==0 or $p->format( "w" )==6) $weekendDays++; //6 - saturday, 0 - sunday
}

echo "<p>Total  days: $totalDays</p><p>Weekend days: $weekendDays </p>";
  $fines = ($totalDays - $weekendDays) * 15;
  echo "₱ ". $fines;
  $fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
  mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
```

Comment: I already change your returnDate into mine also the today already change it into currentdate but the penalties still counting the weekends and I also delete the } from the last because it's getting error

Comment: Aha... Problem was that the sign > and < didn't convert day in week to number. The sign == will do that.

Comment: there's something wrong http://imgur.com/a/4dZU8

Comment: Time part in DateTime can make additional day of difference. If you don't want that, we have to set it to 00:00:00. The newest code will give you output 4 and 2 (without setTime(0,0) it would be 5 and 2). The dates in example are the same as yours. If it still isn't ok, then we should see the way you read your dates from db.

Comment: When I change my date into august 31, the penalties are counting even I already return it http://imgur.com/a/X1UFd , I have date_return , should we not use that?

Comment: can you put borrowdate in your code? so that's why the penalties continuously because the the borrowdate was not included into your code

Answer (score 0):

do like this first find out the dayofweek of current date and check if its sunday or saturday. The value returned form day of week will be in number. 0 means Sunday and through 6 for saturday.

```
   $borrowdate = new Datetime($row['date_return']);
   $returndate = new Datetime($row['due_date']); 
   $currentdate = new Datetime(); 
   $dayofweek = date('w', $currentdate->getTimestamp());       
   $fines = 0;
   if($currentdate > $returndate){
       if($dayofweek != 0){
           $days = $borrowdate->diff($returndate ?? $currentdate, true)->days;
           echo "₱ ". $fines = $days > 0 ? intval(floor($days)) * 15 : 0;
           $fi = $row['borrow_details_id'];
           mysqli_query($dbcon,"update borrowdetails set fines='$fines' where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
       }



   }

   $newquery = mysqli_query($dbcon,"select fines from borrowdetails where borrow_details_id = '$fi'");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($newquery);
   echo $row['fines'];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152930/discussion-on-answer-by-anil-shrestha-how-to-prevent-weekend-include-in-fines-us). If you are having additional problems, edit the question to include the relevant information.